# Asp.net Partial Business Logic Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, class

I have many classes on my application like Profile.cs, Post.Cs , Product.Cs and for database operations dbopertations.cs and businesslogic.cs

For example (for one method)

**dboperations.cs inlcudes** `

```
`  public static List<Post> GetPost()
    {


        try
        {
            xxxx...
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return ....;
    }
```

businesslogic.cs includes

```
  public static List<Post> GetPost()
        {
            return dboperations.GetPost();
        }
```

My businesslogic.cs includes many of methods like above.Is it bad for perfomance ?
Should I divide my businesslogic.cs(4900 line) and dboperations.cs(6000 line) file for good performance ?
While page is loading  is it checking all lines ?

Comment: your code is compiled to a single dll. So it does not matter how many .cs files you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Just In Time compiler will compile your methods as they are called. You won't get a performance boost by separating your code. But you will get a maintainability boost.

However, you may get a slight performance boost if you return iterators rather than materialzed `List`s. This takes advantage of deferred execution and allows a caller to jump out of an iteration before the entire list is retrieved.

Also, do not just `throw` an exception, this is pointless and wasteful. If you are not logging or able to handle the exception in some way then just let it bubble up to someone that knows how to handle it.

Comment: I will use throw exception messages to logging. Thank you.